# Boolean variable alerts as false after being set to true

Tags: javascript, ajax, boolean

I have the following javascript:

```
var wasSuccessfull = false;

$.ajax({
    url: 'url here',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(jsondata),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json'
}).success(function (data, status) {

    if (status == 'success') {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty('d')) {
            if (typeof successCallback === 'function') {
                successCallback(sender, data.d, true);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (typeof successCallback === 'function') {
                successCallback(sender, data.d, true);
            }
        }
    }

    wasSuccessfull = true;

}).fail(function (jqHXR, status, errorThrown) {

    if (typeof failureCallback === 'function') {
        failureCallback(sender, status + ': ' + errorThrown + '<p>StackTrace: ' + jqHXR.responseText + "</p>", true);
    }

});

if (typeof returnTrueOrFalse === 'boolean' && returnTrueOrFalse)
    alert(wasSuccessfull);
```

In the beginning I set `wasSuccessfull` to `false` and later if the ajax call is successfull it gets set to `true` and at the end I `alert()` it out.

Even though `wasSuccessfull` gets set to `true` the `alert()` alerts value: `false` .

Can anybody tell me why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

returnTrueOrFalse must be true so it alerts the initial value of wasSuccessfull.

$.ajax is async, even if your code for alert is placed after the call they will run at the same time, but the result from the ajax call will happen too late. You should change the code if you want your alert to fire when the request is completed(successful or not).

From http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ , you can have a look at complete callback option.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the ajax call is asynchronous, this code:

```
if (typeof returnTrueOrFalse === 'boolean' && returnTrueOrFalse)
    alert(wasSuccessfull);
```

is called before the result is retrieved from the ajax call.

You should alert the value in your success callback.